# Does every instantiated class in spring load default variables from the application.properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

Spring annotations question. I am using a default value like so

```
@Service
public class MyClient{
@Value("${apikey}")
private String apikey;
    public MyClient(){}
}
```

I imagine that every instantiation of this class should initialize the value of apikey to the default value apikey from the application.properties file. Is this not so? I ask because I am finding apikey to be null after I've instantiated MyClient object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is annotated `@Service` and so it is a spring-managed bean. By default all spring beans are singleton so exists in only one instance.

If you try to create this bean manually auto wiring of @value won't work because you bypass the spring initialization.

Btw: it is a bad idea to mix self-managed and spring-managed bean from the same class.